# PHP - Get dimension of HTML tag

Tags: php, render

I'm trying to get some attributes for HTML tags in a web page.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header" class="clearit" role="banner">
    <div id="headerWrapper">
      <ul id="primaryNav" role="navigation">
        <li id="musicNav" class="navItem">
          <a href="/music" class="nav-link">Music</a>
        </li>
        <li id="listenNav" class="navItem">
          <a href="/listen" class="nav-link">Radio</a>
        </li>
        <li id="eventsNav" class="navItem">
          <a href="/events" class="nav-link">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li id="chartsNav" class="navItem">
          <a href="/charts" class="nav-link">Charts</a>
        </li>
        <li id="communityNav" class="navItem">
          <a href="/community" class="nav-link">Community</a>
        </li>
        <li id="originalsNav" class="navItem">
          <a href="http://originals.last.fm" class="nav-link">Originals</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, I need the actual height and width for `#headerWrapper` and compare it with `#musicNav` in my PHP script. Since PHP is server-side, I can't get these attributes so I'm thinking to append Javascript code to calculate these attributes and store them in a JSON file like in this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.ready(function() {
  var JSONObject= {
    "tagname":"headerWrapper",
    "height":$("#headerWrapper").height(),
    "width":$("#headerWrapper").width()
  },
  {
    "tagname":"musicNav",
    "height":$("#musicNav").height(),
    "width":$("#musicNav").width()
  }
  });
});  
</script>
```

Then I'd like to read it in the php file that contains my algorithm to extract visual features from web pages. So I need to render the web page with appended Javascript using some browser. I'm using exec to send the new file to Firefox, like this:

```
exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://localhost/Autoextractor/test.html" 2> errors.txt');
```

And Firefox opens in taskmanager but **does not dispaly**, the page **is not rendered**, and my appended Javascript code **is not executed**.

safe_mode=off - disabled_functions deleted from php.ini and when executing 
    exec("whoami");
The result is my user (note: my user in Administrator group) and I did try [wscript](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86438) with no result.

Does anyone have any idea why it's not working, or has another solution to get the dimensions of HTML tags?

Comment: Do you really need to know the dimensions on the sever-side? Would it not be sufficient to write some JS to take care of everything on the client side?

Comment: The dimensions of an HTML tag are very dependant on the screen size you render it on. Consider `<div style="width: 75%"></div>`. Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply running a browser won't allow you to read any data back from it, so forget about using `system`.

You can use [Selenium Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) to control a browser with PHP, run JavaScript, then return the result.

When you write your real JavaScript, you will need to fix the syntax errors that appear in the example you included in the question.

Keep in mind that the size of elements on screen will depend on factors such as installed fonts, chosen font size, browser, window size, etc. You can get a result for a browser running on your system, but you can't depend on it to be a universal result.

Comment: i wanna send you a cyber high five because u don't know how much u help me thanks again

Answer (score 0):

"have another solution to get Get dimension of HTML tags?"

Something wrong with Firebug/Inspect, which will give you rendered offsets with a few simple operations.

Run your code in a console if you want to do it programmatically, though you'll still need firebug/Inspect to find the right selectors (which really obviates the ability to do any of this automatically).  Trying to log it all... well, it sounds like you're trying to keep a *database*... perhaps you should set one up.

This might be a problem that you need to add more context to get a useful response.